# Google+ article rendering no longer working after adding JSON-LD Schema.org

Tags: google-plus, schema.org, json-ld

I recently updated my blog to use JSON-LD to add Schema.org data to the site. However, I've run into a problem - Google+ article rendering is no longer working.

When I try to share a link from my blog to my Google+ page, it loads the article image, but not the article headline. Article rendering was working fine before when I was relying solely on the Open Graph protocol.

I've run my JSON-LD code through Google's Structured Data Testing Tool and it doesn't report any errors or warnings. No errors are being reported in Google Webmaster Tools either.

Am I overlooking something or doing something wrong?

For reference, here is the most recent blog post I tried to share when I noticed the article headline wasn't loading in:
https://onemoredram.com/2018/07/27/diageo-releasing-trio-of-new-mortlach-expressions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran your JSON-LD through a test; there are two errors actually:

WARNING: the "July 27, 2018" value in the http://schema.org/datePublished field is not a valid date. Dates should be in the ISO 8601 format

ERROR: the validator does not recognize the article prefix, please specify it clearly in the prefix attribute

The full result of the test was:

```
rdfanode
http://ogp.me/ns#title
@value = Diageo Releasing Trio of New Mortlach Expressions | One More Dram
http://ogp.me/ns#type
@value = article
http://ogp.me/ns#url
@value = https://onemoredram.com/2018/07/27/diageo-releasing-trio-of-new-mortlach-expressions/
http://ogp.me/ns#image
http://ogp.me/ns#image:width
@value = 960
http://ogp.me/ns#image:height
@value = 664
@value = https://onemoredram.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/mortlach-12-16-20-year-old-07-27-2018.jpg
http://ogp.me/ns#site_name
@value = One More Dram
http://ogp.me/ns/fb#admins
@value = 571973782956119
http://ogp.me/ns#description
@value = Diageo is releasing a trio of new Mortlach expressions: 12 Year Old The Wee Witchie, 16 Year Old Distiller&#039;s Dram, and 20 Year Old Cowie&#039;s B...
http://dev.twitter.com/cards/markup#card
@value = summary_large_image
http://dev.twitter.com/cards/markup#site
@value = @1moredram
http://dev.twitter.com/cards/markup#domain
@value = onemoredram.com
http://dev.twitter.com/cards/markup#title
@value = Diageo Releasing Trio of New Mortlach Expressions | One More Dram
http://dev.twitter.com/cards/markup#description
@value = Diageo is releasing a trio of new Mortlach expressions: 12 Year Old The Wee Witchie, 16 Year Old Distiller&#039;s Dram, and 20 Year Old Cowie&#039;s B...
http://dev.twitter.com/cards/markup#image
@value = https://onemoredram.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/mortlach-12-16-20-year-old-07-27-2018.jpg

jsonld
@type = http://schema.org/Organization
http://schema.org/name
@value = One More Dram
http://schema.org/url
@id = https://onemoredram.com
http://schema.org/logo
@id = https://onemoredram.com/wp-content/themes/onemoredram/images/og-default-image.jpg
http://schema.org/sameAs
@id = https://www.facebook.com/onemoredram
http://schema.org/sameAs
@id = https://plus.google.com/+onemoredram
http://schema.org/sameAs
@id = https://www.instagram.com/onemoredram
http://schema.org/sameAs
@id = https://www.patreon.com/onemoredram
http://schema.org/sameAs
@id = https://www.twitter.com/1moredram
http://schema.org/sameAs
@id = https://www.youtube.com/onemoredram

jsonld
WARNING: the "July 27, 2018" value in the http://schema.org/datePublished field is not a valid date. Dates should be in the ISO 8601 format
@type = http://schema.org/NewsArticle
http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage
@type = http://schema.org/WebPage
@id = https://onemoredram.com/2018/07/27/diageo-releasing-trio-of-new-mortlach-expressions/
http://schema.org/headline
@value = Diageo Releasing Trio of New Mortlach Expressions
http://schema.org/description
@value = Diageo is releasing a trio of new Mortlach expressions: 12 Year Old The Wee Witchie, 16 Year Old Distiller’s Dram, and 20 Year Old Cowie’s Blue Seal.
http://schema.org/image
@id = https://onemoredram.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/mortlach-12-16-20-year-old-07-27-2018.jpg
http://schema.org/datePublished
@value = July 27, 2018
@type = http://Date
http://schema.org/dateModified
@value = July 27, 2018
@type = http://Date
http://schema.org/author
@type = http://schema.org/Person
http://schema.org/name
@value = Elias Aoude
http://schema.org/publisher
@type = http://schema.org/Organization
http://schema.org/name
@value = One More Dram
http://schema.org/logo
@type = http://schema.org/ImageObject
http://schema.org/url
@id = https://onemoredram.com/wp-content/themes/onemoredram/images/og-default-image.jpg

rdfanode
ERROR: the validator does not recognize the article prefix, please specify it clearly in the prefix attribute
resource = https://onemoredram.com/2018/07/27/diageo-releasing-trio-of-new-mortlach-expressions/
http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#alternate = https://onemoredram.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fonemoredram.com%2F2018%2F07%2F27%2Fdiageo-releasing-trio-of-new-mortlach-expressions%2F
http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#prev = https://onemoredram.com/2018/07/26/johnnie-walker-launching-blue-label-ghost-and-rare-port-ellen/
article:published_time = 2018-07-27T11:30:24Z
https://api.w.org/ = https://onemoredram.com/wp-json/
http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#alternate = https://onemoredram.com/2018/07/27/diageo-releasing-trio-of-new-mortlach-expressions/feed/
article:modified_time = 2018-07-27T18:05:48Z
http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#alternate = https://onemoredram.com/feed/
http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#alternate = https://onemoredram.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fonemoredram.com%2F2018%2F07%2F27%2Fdiageo-releasing-trio-of-new-mortlach-expressions%2F&format=xml
http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#alternate = https://onemoredram.com/comments/feed/

rdfanode
resource = https://onemoredram.com/2018/07/27/diageo-releasing-trio-of-new-mortlach-expressions/
http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#role = http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#search
```

I don't believe Google to be so strict (warning wise) however errors may cause issues where displaying your data properly would incur; I would try and correct these little things incase they are a factor.

This is a sample of the proper schema template (you either have seen this, or can use this to try and troubleshoot your schema):

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{ "@context": "http://schema.org", 
 "@type": "BlogPosting",
 "headline": "14 Ways Json Can Improve Your SEO",
 "alternativeHeadline": "and the women who love them",
 "image": "http://example.com/image.jpg",
 "award": "Best article ever written",
 "editor": "John Doe", 
 "genre": "search engine optimization", 
 "keywords": "seo sales b2b", 
 "wordcount": "1120",
 "publisher": "Book Publisher Inc",
 "url": "http://www.example.com",
 "datePublished": "2015-09-20",
 "dateCreated": "2015-09-20",
 "dateModified": "2015-09-20",
 "description": "We love to do stuff to help people and stuff",
 "articleBody": "You can paste your entire post in here, and yes it can get really really long.",
   "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Steve"
  }
 }
</script>
```

Hope it leads you in the proper direction :)

Comment: Looks like the date may have been the problem even though it cleared Google validation. I corrected the date, created a duplicate post, and tested that on Google+ and it appears to be pulling in all information properly now. I'll have to wait a bit for the Google+ cache to clear before I can try re-submitting the live links again. Thank you!

Comment: I take that back. Even after correcting the Schema timestamp error, Google+ article rendering isn't pulling in all the information it should. I'm stumped.

Comment: I finally figured it out. Google+ does not seem to like multiple snippets on one page. It was pulling the Organization / Social Profile information instead of the Article info. I modified my site to only load the Organization snippet on the home page. Now Google+ is appropriately pulling in Article info.